# BFS reconstructing the path to get shortest path

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, breadth-first-search

I would like to construct a shortest path from a Breadth First Search. I have implemented the BFS in Java code (as shown below), but now I do not know how to reconstruct the path to get the shortest path from the implementation of the code.

While I know I have to keep an array of parents, I do not know where to put it in my code. Basically, I would like to trace back the shortest path using BFS from the start point to goal point. Note that I am using a 2D array.

Am I doing it correctly? Can someone please help me with that?

```
public ArrayList<Point> shortestPath=new ArrayList<>();
public ArrayList<Point> BFS(Point start, Point end){
   int[][] distanceBoard=new int[50][50]; Point current,parent;
    for(int i=0;i<distanceBoard.length;i++)
        for(int j=0;j<distanceBoard.length;j++) distanceBoard[i][j]=Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    distanceBoard[start.getX()][start.getY()]=0;
    LinkedList<Point> q=new LinkedList<>();
    q.addFirst(start);
    while(!q.isEmpty()){
        current=q.getFirst();
        if((new Point(current.getX(),current.getY()))==end) return shortestPath;
        q.removeFirst();
        for(Point point:current.getNeighbours()){
            if(distanceBoard[point.getX()][point.getY()]==Integer.MAX_VALUE){
                distanceBoard[point.getX()][point.getY()]=distanceBoard[current.getX()][current.getY()]+1;
                parent=current;
                q.addLast(point);
            }
            shortestPath.add(current);
        }
    }return null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To backtrack you can just use the parent of the destination point and continue until you reach the place you started... something like

```java
ArrayList < vertex > points = new ArrayList < > ();
while ((current.x != startx) || (current.y != starty)) {
  points.add(current);
  current = current.parent;
}
```

where `startx` and `starty` is the (x,y) position you start from in your grid. You want to do this after you have found the destination your looking for i.e. after you break out of the `while(!q.isEmpty()){...}`.

```java
while (!q.isEmpty()) {
  current = q.dequeue();
  if (current.x == targetx && current.y == targety) break; //quite when path is found
  ...
}
ArrayList < vertex > vertices = new ArrayList < > ();
while ((current.x != startx) || (current.y != starty)) {
  vertices.add(current);
  current = current.parent;
}
```

So the `parent` `Point` is a way of remembering where you came from and so if you have the destination `Point` then you should have the destination `Point`'s `parent` (or previous position) and once you have the destination `Point`'s `parent`you want to find the destination `Point`'s `parent` `parent` and so on until you have the `Point` you began the search at. I also, just to add to your confusion, made a mistake in the `while ((current.x != startx)...)` so instead of it being `while ((current.x != startx) && (current.y != starty))` i changed it to `while ((current.x != startx) || (current.y != start))`  since you don't want to stop iterating when for example you have just the correct y-value, you want it to stop when both sides are false i.e. when both `current.x != startx` and `current.y != start` are false.

Comment: A bit confused, do i do this in the same function or in a new function?

Comment: i edited post ... same function just after while loop